# Merging rows in my pivot table query with multiple pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

The below SQL query is supposed to show a teacher availability. There are 4 possible booking types - AM, PM, Full Day and Hourly. If there's an AM booking, the text in the cell should show PM, if there's a PM booking, it should show AM, if there's a full day booking, or both an AM and a PM booking, it should show 'xxx'. Hourly bookings - It is safe to assume there is only ever going to be 2 hourly bookings for each day, 1 for the AM (start time <= 12pm) and 1 for PM (end time > 12pm), meaning we should show 'xxx'. This all works fine.

The trouble im having is showing 'XXX' when there is an AM booking then a PM hourly booking, or a PM booking with an AM hourly booking.

```
    WITH Bookings AS
    (  SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [0], [1], [2], [3],
            [Status] = CASE 
                        WHEN ([0] > 0 AND [1] > 0) THEN 'XXX'
                        WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'  
                        WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                        WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'  
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND EndTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'   
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND EndTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                        WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'  

                        END
    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, 
                        BookingDate, 
                        BookingDuration, 
                        StartTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MIN(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,
                        EndTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MAX(EndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,                        
                        [x] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays 
                WHERE   (Status = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(x)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt

             WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 6)

    ), PivotedBookings AS
    (   SELECT  *
    FROM    Bookings
            PIVOT
            (   MAX([Status])
                FOR [WeekDay] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])
            ) pvt

    )
    SELECT ID,Firstname,Surname,Band,'£' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DefaultChargeRateDaily) + '/' + '£' + CONVERT(varchar(50), DefaultPayRateDaily) as 'BandRates',Telephone,Mobile,Teacher,TeacherAssistant,KeyStage,MAX(Monday) Monday,MAX(Tuesday) Tuesday,MAX(Wednesday) Wednesday,MAX(Thursday) Thursday,MAX(Friday) Friday, Notes
      FROM (
SELECT  t.ID, 
        t.Firstname, 
        t.Surname, 
        tb.Band,
        t.DefaultChargeRateDaily,
        t.DefaultPayRateDaily,
        t.Telephone,
        t.Mobile,
        t.Teacher,
        t.TeacherAssistant,
        CASE WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year7 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y8' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' END + ' - ' + CASE WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y8' WHEN t.Year7 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' ELSE '' END as 'KeyStage',

        Monday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Monday, '') END,
        Tuesday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 1) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Tuesday, '') END,
        Wednesday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 2) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Wednesday, '') END,
        Thursday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 3) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Thursday, '') END,
        Friday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 4) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Friday, '') END,
        Notes
FROM    Teachers t

        LEFT JOIN PivotedBookings pb
            ON pb.TeacherID = t.ID
        LEFT JOIN TeacherBands tb
            ON tb.ID = t.Band
        LEFT JOIN AvailabilityNotes an 
            ON t.ID = an.TeacherID
            WHERE t.Active = 0 and (t.Status = 1 or t.Status = 0) and t.PrimarySchool = 1 and t.ID = 9094
            ) T1
 GROUP BY ID,Firstname,Surname,Telephone,Mobile,Teacher,TeacherAssistant,KeyStage,Notes,DefaultChargeRateDaily,DefaultPayRateDaily,Band
 ORDER BY Surname,Firstname asc
```

The first part generates the following -

```
SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [0], [1], [2], [3],
            [Status] = CASE 
                            WHEN ([0] > 0 AND [1] > 0) THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'  
                            WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'  
                            WHEN ([3] > 0 AND EndTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00')) AND ([0] > 1) THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN ([3] > 0 AND EndTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00')) AND ([1] > 1) THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND EndTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'   
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND EndTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'                     

                        END
    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, 
                        BookingDate, 
                        BookingDuration, 
                        StartTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MIN(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,
                        EndTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MAX(EndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,                        
                        [x] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays 
                WHERE   (Status = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(x)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt

             WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 6)
```

.

```
TeacherID | WeekDay  | 0     | 1     | 2     | 3     | Status
9094      | Monday   | NULL  | NULL  | 1     | NULL  | XXX
9094      | Tuesday  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 1     | AM
9094      | Wednesday| NULL  | 1     | NULL  | NULL  | AM
9094      | Thursday | NULL  | 1     | NULL  | NULL  | AM
9094      | Thursday | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 1     | PM
9094      | Friday   | NULL  | NULL  | 1     | 1     | XXX
```

Booking Durations -

0 - AM
1 - PM
2 - Full Day
3 - Hourly

We can see here, the two Thursday rows need merging and showing in the status column as XXX, rather than 2 separate rows.

An example is shown in the screenshot below. Highlighted yellow, it is showing PM, however it should show XXX as there is 1 PM hourly and an AM.

[image: Screenshot of what is needed]

How can I get it to show XXX when there is an hourly and a AM or an hourly and a PM?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could post your create table statements and some sample data for each table?  Or even create a sql fiddle with some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the complex logic into two steps, using an IntermediateBookings CTE to reduce the logic to two columns `has_am` and `has_pm`. These are more easy to calculate, and from these, the final output is then easy to calculate as well. In theory, you could just improve the `CASE` expression of your original statement to contain some more `AND`s and `OR`s, but that is not very maintainable. The start of the query should be like this:

```
WITH IntermediateBooking as (
SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [0], [1], [2], [3],
            has_am = case when 
                          [1] > 0
                       OR [2] > 0
                       OR ([3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00'))
                     then 1
                     else null
                     end,
            has_pm = case when 
                          [0] > 0
                       OR [2] > 0
                      OR ([3] > 0 AND EndTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00'))
                     then 1
                     else null
                     end
    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, 
                        BookingDate, 
                        BookingDuration, 
                        StartTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MIN(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,
                        EndTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MAX(EndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,                        
                        [x] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays 
                WHERE   (Status = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(x)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt

             WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'05/06/2013'), 6)
),
Bookings AS (
SELECT TeacherID, [WeekDay],
       case when sum(has_am) > 0 and sum(has_pm) > 0 then 'XXX'
            WHEN sum(has_am) > 0 then 'AM'
            WHEN sum(has_pm) > 0 then 'PM'
       end as [Status]
  FROM IntermediateBookings
GROUP BY TeacherID, [WeekDay]
)
```

The rest - starting with `PivotedBookings` - could stay as you have it.

However, as I do not have the tables available, I cannot check for syntax errors and if the result is as requested. Some tweaks may be necessary.